# Why can't I use += operator on a list iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdlist

I have a iterator from a `std::list<std::string>`, but when I attempt to advance it using `+=`, I get a compilation error.

The code is:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::list<std::string> x;

    x.push_front("British");
    x.push_back("character");
    x.push_front("Coding is unco");
    x.push_back("Society");
    x.push_back("City Hole");
    auto iter = x.begin();
    iter += 3;
    //std::advance(iter, 3);
    x.erase(iter);

    for (auto &e: x) {
        std::cout << e << "\n";
    }
}
```

If I compile this using `clang++ -std=c++11 -o li li.cpp`, I get:

```
li.cpp:13:10: error: no viable overloaded '+='
    iter += 3;
    ~~~~ ^  ~
1 error generated.
```

Why can't I use `+=` with this iterator?

Comment: @EdChum More precisely, you cannot increment a list iterator like that. (+ Op knows about advance, its in comment)

Comment: `iter += 3` means  `iter = iter + 3`, which you can't do.

Comment: provided that the error message is rather clear I dont really understand what the question is

Comment: @Mudi -- no. `iter += 3` means "call the overloaded operator `+=`". Unlike for numeric types, it has no inherent connection to `+`.

Comment: @PeteBecker agreed!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The iterator for [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Member_types) is [BidirectionalIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which doesn't support `operator+=` like [RandomAccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

You can use `operator++`, which is supported by [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) (including `BidirectionalIterator`), something like

```
++iter;
++iter;
++iter;
```

But it's ugly. The best way is as you commented, to use [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) (or [std::next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) (since C++11)) instead, which could be used with [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) (including `BidirectionalIterator`), and also takes advantage of the features supported by `RandomAccessIterator`.

(emphasis mine)

> Complexity
>
> Linear.
>
> However, if `InputIt` additionally meets the requirements of
> `RandomAccessIterator`, **complexity is constant**.

So you can just use it without considering about the category of the iterator, `std::advance` will do the best choice for you. e.g.

```
std::advance(iter, 3);
```

or

```
iter = std::next(iter, 3);
```

Comment: The OP already had this in their code commented out so the use of `advance` is already known, so you don't need to include this bit

Comment: @EdChum it might be helpful to the next viewer of the question.

Comment: @EdChum I added some explanations about `std::advance`. From the question (about iterator category) I think OP might don't understand it enough.

Comment: OK, to be honest I missed this when I commented to the question when it was first posted so it's worth highlighting

Answer (score 6):

The reason is simply that the `+=` operator is not defined for the Bidirectional iterator you are using.

For all iterators there is at least:

- Copy-assignable and destructible, i.e. `X b(a);` and `b = a;`
- Can be incremented, i.e. `++a` and `a++`

Everything else depends on the type of iterator check the table [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/):

[image]

As you see a random-access iterator would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

A `std::list::iterator` is not a [Random Access Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). It is not possible to "jump ahead" several elements in a list, you must iterate through the list until you reach the desired element. You can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) which will deduce the best way to advance the iterator based on the iterator category. In the case of a `std::list::iterator` it will increment the iterator in a loop.